# Quick way to open PHP files in htdocs through localhost via MAMP (OS X)

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

Usually I place my files in the "htdocs" folder and then remember/navigate to the wanted file through the browser.

Is there a way to double click files inside the "htdocs" folder that opens the file in browser through localhost?

Comment: ___Who let the dogs out___ I assume you mean `htdocs` ? :)

Comment: No! Not if the files are/contain PHP script, as PHP wont be run if you dont request the page via the web server

Comment: @RiggsFolly Fixed :) It's a little sad though..